# relational query in yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii, relation

I have two models named `Statement.php` and `Images.php`

In my `statement.php` model i have a relation saying

```
'images'=>array(self::HAS_MANY,'Images','statement_id'),
```

you know what i mean by this line,

Now , i want to execute this relational query ,

```
$data = Statement::model()->with('images')->findall($criteria);
```

this query only returns the columns of `Statement` table not the `Images` table why?

Comment: have you written the belongs to in the images model as well?

Answer (score 0):

how you take pictures? example `$data->images->id`

Answer (score 0):

If you have made sure that there is data in the Images table then

```
$data = Statement::model()->with('images')->findall($criteria);
```

will give you the desired output.
Now if you want to access the Images table data then for that you will have to use

```
$data->images
```

You cant access the Images data directly.**For that you will have to use the relation name.**